# print csv file with header(column names) with empty dataset in spark java

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

I've to print the dataset in .csv file but condition is

1) **if dataset is empty than I've to only print the header (which is column names with pipe delimiter) in csv file** like

ID|FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|GRADE

2) and if dataset is not empty than print header with data in csv file

**need the solution for 1st point**

2nd point is working with this code

```
dataset.toDF().coalesec(1).write().format("csv")
   .option("delimiter","|")
   .option("header","true")
   .option("nullValue",null)
   .mode(Savemode.Overwrite)
   .save("path");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with OSS, which is being fixed in Spark 3 version.

Here is the jira ticket about the issue

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26208

Here is the pull request for the fix, which will be merged

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/23173